# How do I count the number of shown sprites?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game and I'm trying to make it wait until the number of a certain sprite shown is equal to 0 before continuing, I tried doing this:

```
NSLog("Number of asteroid 1 nodes: %d", self["Asteroid1Txt"].count)
```

but that gives you the number of a certain sprite, even when its not shown in the screen.

Is there a way to get the number of a certain sprite, only if its actually on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give sprite node a name like this:

```
var mySprite = SkSpriteNode(imageNamed: "nameOfYourImage")
mySprite.name = "spriteToTrack"
```

Then enumerate throught sprites with name "spriteToTrack" like this:

```
var countSprites = 0
enumerateChildNodesWithName(""spriteToTrack""){node,_ in
     countSprites++
     /* If you want to manipulate this node or  remove it....but dont do it in this loop! 
     let tmpNode = node as! SKSpriteNode // Must be the same as mySprite
     */
}

println("I have \(countSprites ) sprites with name spriteToTrack")
```